# What does derivation $(df_p(v))(g)=v(g \circ f)(p)$ really mean?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

What does derivation $(df_p(v))(g)=v(g \circ f)(p)$ really mean?

It's said that $df_p(v) \in T_{f(p)}(N)$ is treated as a derivation which when applied to $g$ results in the directional derivative of $g$. By the R.H.S. this derivative is defined by forming $f \circ g$ and "computing its directional derivative at $p$ using $v$". Or i.e. the directional derivative of $g$ on $N$ is defined as the directional derivative of $f \circ g$.

I don't understand how $v(g \circ f)p$ is a directional derivative. Is it perhaps shorthand for

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow} \frac{g \circ f(x+vh, y+vh,...)-g \circ f(x,y,...)}{h}$$

and $p=(x,y,...)$.

Comment: Do you understand a tangent vector $v$ as a function $v:C^\infty(M)\to\Bbb R$?

Comment: @edm One constructs tangent vectors by differentiating at a point (to different directions). But I don't understand why they should be real numbers, rather then vectors.

Comment: Particularly, about this question I don't understand what the notation $v (g \circ f)(p)$ means, because I read it means $v (multiplied) (g \circ f) (takes as parameter)p$.

Comment: Are you studying smooth manifolds from a book or some online sources? It would help if we know where and how you learn it.

Comment: @edm Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. p. 55 gives the definition for $dF_p(v)$ as the derivation of $F(p)$ that acts on $f \in C^{\infty}(N)$ by the rule $dF_p(v)(f)=v(f \circ F)$. But the reason for the notation $v(f \circ F)$ remains very vague.

Comment: @edm Also, this is probably what's meant by $v$ being a function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector#Definition. But I don't understand how $v$ being a multiplier makes it a function? Or is this "product of functions"? Or perhaps it means a function in the sense as "the dot production is a function"?

Comment: What do you mean by multiplier?

Comment: @edm Since it's written $v(g \circ f)(p)$ then I read that between $v$ and $(g \circ f)$ there's the common multiplier operation. But in that context it's possibly the dot product. In which case it's weird, why is it not written $v \cdot (g \circ f) (p)$. Maybe it's implicit, since $v$ is a vector (since it's an element of a tangent space).

Comment: @edm However, I also don't understand how can the derivative part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Tangent_vectors_as_directional_derivatives be $f \circ F$. Like why is $f \circ F=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{df}{dx^i}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems to me that you are confusing standard definition of tangent vector in differential geometry and isomorphism $T_pV\cong V$ for $V$ a vector space.

**Def.** (tangent vector) Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $C^\infty(M)$ the space of smooth functions on $M$. A linear functional $v$ on $C^\infty(M)$ is called *tangent vector* at point $p$ if $$v(fg) = v(f)g(p)+f(p)v(g).$$

From this definition it follows that $v(g\circ f)$ should be interpreted as linear functional $v\colon C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb R$ evaluated at function $g\circ f\in C^\infty(M)$.

In a special case when the manifold is a (finite dimensional) vector space $V$, there is an isomorphism $V\to T_pV$ that sends vector $v\in V$ to linear functional $f\mapsto \frac d{dt}f(p + tv)|_{t=0}$, which is precisely directional derivative $D_vf(p)$. It is easy to check that this satisfies Leibniz rule.

Finally, for a smooth map $f\colon M\to N$, we can define a linear map $df_p\colon T_pM\to T_{f(p)}N$ in the following way: if $v\in T_pM$, then $df_p(v)$ should be a linear functional on $C^\infty(N)$, so for a smooth function $g\colon N\to \mathbb R$, we define $$(df_p(v))(g) = v(g\circ f).$$

Comment: Yeah this clarifies it. This is actually given in the Lee's book as well, but I was just very confused about the notation.

Comment: @mavavilj, glad to help. I know it's in the book, but I also know that it can be confusing at first since we are used to $\mathbb R^n$ too much where we can identify bunch of different stuff (and usually do).

Answer (score 0):

First we introduce the objects. Let $F\colon M \to N$ be a smooth map between two manifolds. It maps points on $M$ to points on $N$. Also let $g\colon N \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real function on $N$; it maps points on $N$ to real numbers. And finally, let $v \in T_p M$ be a tangent vector at the point $p$ on $M$.

**Interpretation of $\bigl(dF_{p}(v)\bigr)(g)$.** The tangent map $dF_p$ maps the vector $v\in T_p M$ to a vector $dF_p(v) \in T_{F(p)}N$. The function $g$ is a function on $N$. Since $dF_p (v)$ is a tangent vector to $N$ at the point $F(p)$ and $g$ is a function on $N$, it makes sense to look at the directional derivative $\bigl(dF_{p}(v)\bigr)(g)$. (This is interpreting the definition of a tangent vector on $N$.)

**Interpretation of $v(g\circ F)(p)$.** The composition $g\circ F$ is a function from the manifold $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Since $v\in T_p M$ is a vector tangent to $M$, and $g\circ F$ is a real function on $M$, the directional derivative $v(g \circ F)(p)$ makes sense. (Note that this is also the definition of a tangent vector, but now we are working on $M$.)

These are the interpretations of both sides of the equations. If these are unclear, it might be helpful to revise the definition of a tangent vector.

Comment: But what does one need $F$ for?

Comment: I'm thinking that the key to my question might be in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations. Is $F$ perhaps serving the same role as a chart $\varphi$, which is required in order to make $f \in C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Particularly in this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#The_derivative_of_a_map one sees the $\varphi$ again.

Comment: Yes. I wrote $F$ instead of the small $f$ (as in your question). I wanted to stress that $F$ and $g$ are not the same type of maps. You also used $F$ yourself in the comment section under the question...

Comment: So perhaps one can also say that the derivative is taken with respect to the *coordinate representation* of $f$? I.e. $f \circ \varphi^{-1}$?

Comment: I guess so, because Lee writes in his book that: "In other words, $\partial / \partial x^i |_p$ is just the derivation that takes the $i$th partial derivative of (the coordinate representation of) $f$ at (the coordinate representation of) $p$. The vectors $\partial / \partial x^i |_p$ are called the coordinate vectors at $p$ associated with the given coordinate system."

Comment: No, not exactly. I think you also want to ask a second question: "Let $M$ be a manifold, $x\colon U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to M$ a chart around a point $p\in M$. If $v \in T_p M$, then there are constants $a_i$ such that $v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$". If this is what you want, I suggest you ask a new question, because this is not clear in the original question.

Comment: Then what's $F$ and what's it needed for?

Comment: $F$ is the map $f$ in your question.

Comment: Which does what?